# How to extract 5 number and nanmes from the list

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a spreadsheet in which I have user ,numbers ,scored and names. how I can get list lost 5 user have scored maximum between dates .I want show user name with date and higer number scored.
Data screenshot:

[image]

I have tried this formula and successfully got  maximum value

```
=MAX(IF(B2:B15>=G4, IF(B2:B15<=G5, C2:C15)))
```

Comment: it is not unique, as it does not get number between 2 dates

Comment: It ranks a subgroup within a larger group according to one or more columns of criteria. That is the essence of your question here.

Comment: NO THIS TO GET  UNIQUE VALUES AND MY QUESTION IS TO GET TOP HIGHEST VALES.

Comment: You do understand what RANK does don't you?

Comment: no I don't want to get the rank. I want users and there number